# flutter firebase storage throwing unknown error

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

edit: i notice that the code only runs till the below code and then gets out with the error. also, do note that the code provided used to work today

```
void pickUploadGalleryImage() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 512,
      maxHeight: 512,
      imageQuality: 100,
    );

    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("member_profile_pictures/${fileName+getRandomString(50)}");
```

i am trying to upload a profile picture to firebase storage and then display it on a circular avatar. my code is as follows.

```
void pickUploadCameraImage() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 512,
      maxHeight: 512,
      imageQuality: 100,
    );

    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("member_profile_pictures/${fileName + getRandomString(50)}");

    await ref.putFile(File(image!.path));

    ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
      print(value);
      setState(() {
        imageUrl = value;
      });
    });
  }

  void pickUploadGalleryImage() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 512,
      maxHeight: 512,
      imageQuality: 100,
    );

    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("member_profile_pictures/${fileName+getRandomString(50)}");

    await ref.putFile(File(image!.path));

    ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
      print(value);
      setState(() {
        imageUrl = value;
      });
    });
  }
```

however, the terminal is throwing me with this error.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.
```

i have tried to deleting the firebase storage bucket and recreating a new one but it is still giving me this error. tia for all inputs

Comment: Did you checked the rules inside the firebase storage? Make sure they are set to read and write data.

Comment: yes, they are set to read and write for public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update: turns out, i have to use a vpn where my storage is located to access the file. everything works as it should be now

Comment: Oh, if that solved it, then that's great. But it's surprising. Because the other parts of Firebase in your project could also be interacting with the same location as storage. It's fine. I have a question. The Google account that you used in signing in to the Firebase CLI, was it the same account that created the Firebase project? At times, if this is not the case, you might experience storage-unknown error

Comment: yes, same account. took me hours to solve this but what i did was i ran it on my device and it was throwing me the image url but when i clicked it, it says "access denied" which got me thinking about using vpn. sucks that i picked 'US' as the location but im actually residing in Singapore

Comment: I don't think you been in Singapore and the project been US is a problem. About "access denied", are the Firebase Storage rules properly configured? Also, are you running from the web? CORS could be an issue too.

Comment: whenever i use a vpn that is based in the US, no issues occurs. rules are configured correctly.  and what’s cors?

Comment: Wow, that's surprising, that's about the VPN. But it's fine. For CORS, checkout [this part of the Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/web-images#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors). It mainly affects browsers. CORS is Cross Origin Resource Sharing and it sets in anytime domains are different. That's why I asked if you were using Flutter web, it mainly affects there.

Comment: *firebaser here* We've heard from multiple developers in Singapore that they're having problems connecting to Cloud Storage through Firebase. I provided an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075451/firebase-storage-only-showing-when-on-certain-vpn) and will update that as we learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as prefixStorage;

final int timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
final XFile? image = await picker.pickVideo(source:ImageSource.gallery);
final prefixStorage.Reference firebaseStorageRef = firebaseStorage
            .ref()
            .child('images')
            .child(
                '/$timestamp${image?.path.substring(image.path.indexOf('.'), image.path.length)}');
await firebaseStorageRef.putData(await image.readAsBytes());
final String? imageURL = await firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL();
```

Comment: still throwing me the same error

Comment: Did you register your app in [App Check](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/twinr-api-server-stage/appcheck/apps)?

Comment: i did not register in app check but it still used to work before i recreated the ios folder

Comment: I have the same problem this morning that i can't upload my file on firebase storage, after setting App Check it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a child when you are uploading image to 'member_profile_pictures'.

```
void pickUploadCameraImage() async {
        final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.camera,
          maxWidth: 512,
          maxHeight: 512,
          imageQuality: 100,
        );
    
        Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child("member_profile_pictures").child('${fileName + getRandomString(50)}');
    
        await ref.putFile(File(image!.path));
    
        ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
          print(value);
          setState(() {
            imageUrl = value;
          });
        });
      }
    
      void pickUploadGalleryImage() async {
        final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.gallery,
          maxWidth: 512,
          maxHeight: 512,
          imageQuality: 100,
        );
    
        Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child("member_profile_pictures").child('${fileName + getRandomString(50)}');

    
        await ref.putFile(File(image!.path));
    
        ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
          print(value);
          setState(() {
            imageUrl = value;
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: nope, still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Im also in Singapore and facing firebase storage upload issue from this morning (yesterday still no issue), our own system haven't update anything.

Comment: is you're firebase storage located in nam5?

Comment: My GCP default resource location is nam5, but the storage bucket am facing this issue is in asia.

Comment: have you tried using a vpn?

Comment: Looks like cloud storage for firebase having issue in Singapore right now, https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/gAJbQsuZv3kiuNbjQHvP#gtQEJkfLUBhaJqDUrYio